# Places to visit in Denver

Tags: usa, sightseeing

I'm in Colorado at the moment, more specifically at Boulder and I want to know what places I should visit while I'm here. I want to go to the Denver Museum of Nature but besides that I don't know any other fun places to go to. I'm not that much of a "sporty" person so going to the mountains although beautiful and enchanting is not really for me.

Edit:

I enjoy most things related with science or with music, so that would probably be what I want to see. Oh and I enjoy all sorts of bizarre things. Even spooky things!

Comment: Hi El Developer, welcome to Travel.SE. While you have given some idea of what you're NOT interested in, you haven't given much idea of what you ARE interested in. Please edit your question to be more specific otherwise I am afraid this question will need to be closed.

Comment: Hi Ankur, I have added more details, hopefully that will be helpful :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Beer!

The Denver/Boulder Metro area is home to some of the nations best breweries, and a bunch of them do tours. Personally, I'd suggest the trio of a trip up to Fort Collins for the brewer of Fat Tire Amber Ale, New Belgium Brewing, where you'll get to drink the best stuff out of my suggestions, down to Golden for the Coors brewery, where you'll get to see the large scale industrial stuff, and any of the many walking tours that go through the various brewpubs in downtown Denver as a third option.

Comment: I have already tried lots of beers here, I LOVE THEM :D I will definitely consider catching some of those tours, thanks for the recommendation, if anyone else has another recommendation, I'm open to read them!

Comment: If you do go to Coors you'll be in Golden, so go check out "Golden's second largest brewery" called the Golden City Brewery (http://gcbrewery.com/).  The beer, and the sights are great!

Answer (score 0):

If you like music and historic, small venues you should check out Chautauqua Park.

http://www.chautauqua.com/music.php

The venue is easily accessible from the freeway, but nestled among the Boulder foothills with beautiful view of the Flatirons. The Flatirons are the predominant rock features that face Boulder from the foothills. There is a very quaint, historic restaurant on the property. The property also include a small park and lots of great hiking trails.

The venue attracts both small and large name acts but has the cozy feel of a small venue.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on your answer, explain why it's a great venue, etc?